# Integrate CKEditor in Meteor

Tags: meteor, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor in a meteor application:
My attemps:

1. Put CKEditor folder with all the files (js, css, lang, plugins and skins) in the public folder, include the reference to the javascript file (ckeditor.js) in the header and use the appropiate class in textarea elements. Failed because the editor only works if the textarea is in the body (in any template the textarea control remains unmodified).
2. Put the javascript files (ckeditor.js, config.js, styles.js) in client/lib/compatibility folder and the remaining files in the public folder. This time the application cant locate the files (skins, plugins, ...) because is looking for localhost:3000/client/lib/compatibility/ckeditor/ ...

Has anybody make this integration works before?

Answer (score 11):

I got this working and wanted to post a solution for future visitors. First, you need to put everything from the CKEDITOR build download in the public folder. CKEDITOR comes with all sorts of stuff and references everything based on relative directories.

Your public folder should have a directory named ckeditor it should contain contain the following files and folders:

```
 adapters
 lang
 plugins
 skins
 ckeditor.js
 config.js
 contents.css
 styles.js
```

In your primary layout file reference CKEDITOR like so:

```
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
```

In your template:

```
 <template name="yourTemplate">
   <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
 </template>
```

Finally, in the rendered function of your template:

```
 Template.yourTemplate.rendered = function() {
   $('#content').ckeditor();
 };
```

Normally, you would say `this.$('#content').ckeditor()` but that doesn't work because CKEDITOR is in your public folder. As a result, you need to the global reference to the `#content` element.

Answer (score 3):

Put only the CKEditor files that you would've included in `<head>` inside a folder in **client/lib**, i.e. **client/lib/ckeditor**. That's all you need to do to get them served to the client: there's no need to reference anything in any `<head>` or anything like that. All .js and .css files that Meteor finds inside **client** are automatically concatenated and served to the client. This applies to any client-side library, not just CKEditor.

The next thing you need to do is cause CKEditor to be initialized on the pages that use it. Say you have a template called *edit* with a `textarea` with an ID of *editor*. And say you're also loading the CKEditor [jQuery Adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery). Inside a JavaScript file within **client**, put:

```
Template.edit.rendered = function() {
  $('#editor').ckeditor();
}
```

The key here is that the initialization happens after the `textarea` *editor* exists and is ready, because this code is executed after the *edit* template is fully rendered. It will be reexecuted anytime *edit* is rerendered. Any other client-side library is included and initialized similarly.

**EDIT** Image files referenced via .css are a pain in Meteor. The "proper" way to deal with them is to put them all under the folder **public**, in this case for example **public/ckeditor**. Then edit the CKEditor .css files so that all references to image URLs point to your new folder at the root, i.e. **/ckeditor/image1.png** etc. (leave out "public").

Comment: This way the library cant find the icons of the editor and the indicated call inside the "rendered" funtion don't works.
`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ckeditor'`

Comment: To fix the icons, you have a few options: 1. The easiest is to just load CKEditor via a CDN; see http://cdnjs.com/libraries/ckeditor/. To do it this way, you just include the relevant .js and .css files in the `<head>` of your index.html. 2. The most "Meteoric" way would be to move the icon files into /public/ckeditor or similar and edit your CKEditor's skin's .css files to find and replace "url(images/" to "url(/public/ckeditor/". 3. Lastly you could put all of CKEditor inside /public and call it directly in the `<head>` of your index.html, but this loses all performance improvements.

Comment: As for why the `ckeditor()` call fails, there are many ways to initialize CKEditor per the docs (inline, framed, automatic, etc.). First check that you've included the CKEditor JavaScript correctly by loading the page then going into the console and typing `CKEDITOR` to see if the global variable is defined. If it isn't, follow my instructions above. If it is, then follow the instructions in the CKEditor docs to initialize it the way you prefer; I chose the jQuery method, which requires also loading the adapter (see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery).